# How do I select all text from a file with nano?

Tags: linux, copy-paste, nano

I open a file in Ubuntu nano editor from the comand line and I want to copy all the contents of the file so I can paste it in an another application outside the shell.

So far I can only copy using <kbd>shift</kbd> on the screen that is visible but not on all content.

Comment: Are you in a command line only environment?  If not, why don't you open the file in something like gedit?

Comment: I don't have gedit on that machine and I want to learn to do it in nano.

Comment: Btw this is why I hate linux and the command-line: In theory a wonderful thing, but in reality extremely unuintutive, even the most simple and common things don't work like expected. Usability Super-Fail.

Comment: nano is not powerful. just to edit some config files it is pretty ok, but as an code editor it sucks!

Comment: Question is too vague and the answers are all over the map as a result, leading to confusion. Typically you use nano on a remote server, not your desktop computer. This sounds more like a question about your terminal emulator, which is how you access nano. I really think the question should be changed or flagged for removal.

Comment: Agree with above the answers here are confusing

Comment: Thats why `vim` is much better.

Comment: try cat command and copy the content.

Comment: The general way to select all (for Nano's clipboard, anyhow) is to do `ctrl+home` then `ctrl+shift+end` and then `alt+6` to copy. This isn't an answer because it doesn't answer the entire question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't use the buffer of `nano` to use it elsewhere, you need to use the buffer of X or Gnome.

[xclip](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xclip/) is the solution.

> A command line interface to the X11 clipboard. It can also be used for copying files, as an alternative to sftp/scp, avoiding password prompts when X11 forwarding has already been setup.

Answer (score 141):

There is a possible way:

- Cursor at the beginning of a file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> to set a mark
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> (or try <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>) to cut to the end of the file
- If <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> doesn't work, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd>
- to just copy the file content do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to uncut the text again

Comment: nice trick, but I wanted a copy not a cut.

Comment: this works only inside `nano` - after you'll close it you can not uncut it in another app as OP wanted.

Comment: how do you get text OUT of nano? that's what I need to figure out

Comment: I needed to press Alt-A to mark on a MAC

Answer (score 81):

you can use cat and then copy it from the console:

```
cat path/to/file.yml
```

Select the output printed in the console.

Comment: This is simple and efficient

Comment: Simplest one, no complicated step.

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively you can zoom out using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to fit all the file contents on 'one screen page' and select everything using the mouse. After you zoom back with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> or zoom in progressively with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>.

*I don't like the mouse part, but this is a fast way to copy bulk text in nano.*

Comment: Easy and interesting. It works even on very large files.

Comment: It's incredible how simple and creative ideas can solve hard problems.

Comment: I think so, that was very funny, this guy is amazing lol, Why didn't I think about it earlier?

Comment: Thats badasssss.....

Comment: Amazing, thank you! Of note: it only works with the +/- keys on the main part of the keyboard, not the num pad (even when num lock is ON).

Comment: why is it that even a simple cut and paste to the keyboard buffer is so incredibly difficult to do hacks like this are required?

Answer (score 7):

Actually, this answer might be a bit late but I was looking for an answer for the same question and I just figured it out. when you have the file you want to copy to open in nano. you can hit ctl-R and enter the file you want copied from. this will bring in the whole file.

In my case I was just copying my old fstab so it wasn't a big deal. but could get ridiculous with huge files.

Answer (score 3):

You can cut from the current cursor position to the end of the file with meta key plus T. Meta key is either alt or escape, depending on your keyboard. For me, accessing Ubuntu via ssh from my OSX it was escape.

Answer (score 3):

Here's another solution. One that I personally prefer.
It uses Xsel. It's very similar to Xclip but with a key difference.

```
$ cat my_funky_file | xsel
```

While Xclip puts everything in the main clipboard, Xsel manipulates the selection buffer letting you paste the selection with a middle-click. This is great for one-offs! So if you have something in your clipboard that you haven't pasted yet, that would stay unaffected!

And if you want to paste the content, `xsel -o`  will spit it right out.

You can install it on a debian based system using

```
$ apt-get install xsel
```

The source is available [here](https://github.com/kfish/xsel) otherwise! Hope this helps someone.

Comment: xsel: Can't open display: (null)
: Inappropriate ioctl for device

Answer (score 3):

Simplest way:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> to go to the top of the file.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> to set a mark.
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>/</kbd> to go to the bottom of the file (i.e. marking all the text).
- <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> to copy the selected text.

(Not part of the question but for the record, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> can be used to paste copied text.)

Answer (score 2):

use `micro` instead of `nano` in these cases

To install:

```
sudo su
cd /opt/
apt-get install curl
curl https://getmic.ro | bash
ln -s /opt/micro /usr/bin/micro
ln -s /opt/micro /usr/bin/nani
exit
```

so you can open a file with:

```
micro Readme.txt
or
nani Readme.txt
```

I use both, nano is quick and handy, micro is fully featured.

You can use:

- `Ctrl-A` to select all.
- `Ctrl-C`, `Ctrl-V`
- Place multiple cursors if you use `Ctrl` and `left click`
- `Ctrl-Q` to exit and press y or n
- etc..
- [Micro Gihub page](https://github.com/zyedidia/micro/wiki/Installing-Micro)

Answer (score 1):

As other replies have pointed out, it is actually not possible to copy from nano to the Ubuntu clipboard and use it in other software, unless you use your mouse and copy with the right click.

however it is possible to open both files in nano and copy from one to another: (<kbd>Meta</kbd> is <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd> based on your default Meta key)

1. First you need to activate multiple buffers

   - if you have the nano open <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>
   - or open nano with -F flag: `nano -F`
   - or put `set multibuffer` into your `~/.nanorc` file
2. Then you can open files in new buffer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>r</kbd>
3. switch between buffers with <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>,</kbd> to left and <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to right
4. go to the beginning of the file <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>\</kbd> and then you have two options:

   a. mark the text by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>6</kbd>, then take the cursor to the end <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>, then cut the text <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>

   b. cut the text to the end of file by <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>t</kbd>
5. switch to the other file opened in the other buffer and past by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>u</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding it is not possible to select an entire file in nano if it scrolls more then your window.  If you are using a GUI and have nano open from a terminal and the file is not longer than your window you can use mouse and select all the text than cnt+shift+c will copy it to clipboard.

Although not in nano, there is a way in vim.  See [here](http://bullium.com/support/vim.html).

Specifically, select text (visual mode) section.

Answer (score 0):

So this works in putty.
1. right click title bar
2. change settings
3. Appearance
4. change - font
5. change the font to 1

This will put a  lot of code on a single screen.  It was enough for me to copy a large config file.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why everyone decided to make this so hard.

`cat /path/to/file.cfg`

it'll output all text in the terminal that can be selected with standard commands.

Paste where you want it.

Comment: The question was how to do this from within the `nano` editor, which may or may not be possible.

Comment: Reason I mentioned this, was I was trying to do the same thing. Then you just right click in `nano` window and it pasts the text. Downvoting isnt convenient.

Comment: this is a valid answer even when this solution was already in place
https://superuser.com/a/1231864/752096

Comment: I was about to put this answer. Even though the question was how to do it in nano, it's still valid because the desired outcome was to copy ALL text and paste it outside the shell. This is the easiest way I can think of without needing to download any extra tools.

We don't need to be so complicated all the time, lol.

Answer (score 0):

I know that a lot of people already answered this question, but I can't see anyone mentioned this one, it is easy to remember, fast and efficient:

**Hold down** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> **all together**

now select your text with

**Arrow Down**
<kbd>↓</kbd>

and if you want to **cut** the selected text:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>